# ¿Cuál es la complejidad algoritmica de este programa? for dentro de un while

Tags: complejidad

¿Podrían ayudarme con la complejidad de este algoritmo?
No comprendo que valor tendría el `for` si está dentro del `while` y el valor del segundo `while` estando dentro de ese `for`

```
int algoritmo1(int a[], int n) {
    int k, x, i;
    if (n < 3) return -1;
    x = n; i = 0;
    while (i < n - 2) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n - 1; j++) {
            k = j + 1;
            while (k < n) {
                k++; x = x + (a[i] * a[j] * a[k - 1]);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: No creo que tu pregunta sea de Python...

Answer (score 1):

La complejidad del algoritmo que presentas es ***O(n^3)***.

Vamos a asumir una subrutina ***f()*** que se ejecuta en tiempo constante.
Queremos saber cuántas veces llamamos a esta subrutina en función de ***n***.

Ahora bien, si solo tuvieras el while más externo, tendríamos algo así

```
int i = 0;
while (i < n - 2) {
    f() // Recuerda que una llamada a esta función es constante
    i++;
}
```

Tomemos algunos valores de n para ver cuantas veces se llama la subrutina f.

**Para n = 2**

Se llama 0 veces por lo que la condición del ciclo no se cumple ni la primera vez.

**Para n = 4**

La subrutina f será llamada 2 veces. (i = 0, i = 1)

**Para n = 100**

La subrutina f será llamada 98 veces.

En general

La subrutina f se llamará ***O(n-2)*** veces.

Ahora bien, cuando hablamos de complejidad algorítmica, nos preocupamos por la tasa a la que crece un algoritmo con respecto a la entrada, por lo que las constantes se omiten.

Entonces tenemos que esta parte es ***O(n)***.

Ahora, seguimos con el ciclo for.

```
 int i = 0;
 while (i < n - 2) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n - 1; j++) {
        f();
    }
    i++;
}
```

Sabemos que el while se ejecuta ***O(n)*** veces. La pregunta es entonces ¿cuantas veces se ejecuta el for por cada una de esas n veces?.

**Para n = 5**

> **Para i = 0**;
> f será llamada cuando j = 1, 2, 3 (3 veces)

> **Para i = 1**;
> f será llamada cuando j = 2, 3 (2 veces)

> **Para i = 2**;
> f será llamada cuando j = 3 (1 vez)

Por lo que tenemos que el número total de veces que se llama a f es 3+2+1 cuando n = 5.

Para el caso general esto se reduce a una sumatoria.

1 + 2 + ... + (n-3) + (n-2) = (n-2) * (n-1) / 2

(n-2) * (n-1) / 2 = O(n^2)

Tenemos que la complejidad es de O(n^2)

Finalmente, al agregar el ciclo más anidado.

```
int i = 0;
int k = 0;
 while (i < n - 2) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n - 1; j++) {
        k = j + 1;
        while (k < n) {
            f();
            k++;
        }
    }
    i++;
}
```

Ya sabemos que el while más afuera y el for son ***O(n^2)***.

Analicemos el mismo caso que teníamos antes cuando n = 5.

> Para i = 0, j = 1; f será llamado cuando k = 2, 3, 4 (3 veces)

> Para i = 0, j = 2; f será llamado cuando k = 3, 4 (2 veces)

> Para i = 0, j = 3; f será llamado cuando k = 4 (1 vez)

> Para i = 1, j = 2; f será llamado cuando k = 3, 4 (2 veces)

> Para i = 1, j = 3; f será llamado cuando k = 4 (1 vez)

> Para i = 2, j = 3; f será llamado cuando k = 4 (1 vez)

En total se llamó 10 veces.

En general la subrutina f se llama la siguiente cantidad de veces.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nótese que aunque 5^3 = 125, solo se ejecuta 10 veces para ese caso f.
Esto es porque este tipo de análisis se preocupa para cuando la entrada se vuelve más grande. Por ejemplo, este algoritmo resulta impráctico si hubiesen 10000 elementos, por lo que la subrutina f se ejecutaría cerca de 166x10^9 veces.

Como curiosidad la sumatoria anterior es igual a

***O(n + n(n + 1)(n - 4) / 6)***

***O(n^3/6 - n^2/2 + n/3)***

Comment: A esto es a lo que me referia el orden mas exacto es como tu dices O(n^3/6-n2/2+n^3), decir que solo es O(n^3) es muy general

Answer (score 0):

Tanto el `while` como el `for`, son bucles.

Dicho de manera coloquial, estás iterando un bucle, en un bucle, en un bucle.

Por lo tanto, estamos hablando de una matriz tridimensional, es decir un **algoritmo de complejidad O(n³)**. Y así sucesivamente a medida que añades bucles. Por ejemplo, si colocases todo tu algoritmo dentro de otro for (bucle) sería O(n⁴).

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: No se si lo de matriz tridimensional venga al caso. En el código del OP solo es un arreglo.

Comment: @JhonRayo99 precisamente un arreglo es una matriz de 1 dimensión

Comment: Si, de acuerdo, pero y lo de matriz tridimensional de donde sale?

Comment: @TomuRain, realmente no es tan así, que halla 3 ciclos no necesariamente quiere decir que el orden sea O(n3), bien podría ser O(n3 + nlog(n)) o cualquier otro orden, n3 es cuando todos los ciclos hacen la misma cantidad de iteraciones ej todos van de 1 a 5, y por otra parte que haya 3 ciclos anidados no quiere decir que estés recorriendo una matriz tridimensional, en este caso particular no creo que el orden sea O(n3)

Comment: De hecho si es O(n^3). Solo pues que lo que dices si es cierto, la justificación no es que haya 3 ciclos. La razón es que el bucle más externo se ejecuta n-2 veces que viene a ser lo mismo que n en términos asintóticos. Luego el for se ejecuta (n-2+n-3+...) (n-2) veces. Que es O(n^2). Y lo mismo sucede con el while más anidado. Y se concluye que es O(n^3). Aunque fácilmente yo podría tener un ciclo que sea O(logn). Por ejemplo la implementación iterativa de búsqueda binaria.

Comment: @JhonRayo99, creo que no entendiste lo que quise decir, el orden del algoritmo no es O(n3), es O(n3 + otracosa), seria muy fácil decir que porqué tiene 3 ciclos anidados, es O(n3), creo que el ejercicio requiere más precisión

Comment: @Japv Sí es O(n^3). No es porque sea fácil, sino porque n^3 tiene mayor coeficiente. Si estuviéramos hablando de un resultado del estilo O(n^3 + n), a medida que n tiende a infinito, se tiende a n^3. Por eso es O(n^3). Por ejemplo, con un n=50, n^3+n es 125000+50 (muy cercano a n^3=125000), y cada vez más pequeña la diferencia entre n^3 y n^3+n. Mi respuesta fue una forma muy simplista de detectar un O(n^3) ya que los bucles se recorren una cantidad i,j y k fijas (similar a una matriz tridimensional), pero sí debí aclarar que es solo para cuando i, j y k se recorran en su totalidad.

Comment: @TomuRain, yo se que es O(n3), solo me refería a que la respuesta debía ser más exacta

Comment: @TomuRain, me refería a que hay que aclarar más las cosas ya que por ej, O(n3 + n2), no es lo mismo que decir          O(n3 - log(n)), hay uno más eficiente que otro, aunque los dos sean O(n3),

Comment: @Japv De hecho arriba dijiste que el orden de complejidad del algoritmo no es O(n³), lo cual puede generarle confusión al lector.  Presentar un orden de complejidad como O(n3 + n2) y O(n3 - log(n)) es como si presentases un resultado como 7+0 o 7-0, por eso es que se simplifica. Como es imposible analizar el caso promedio, siempre se analiza el peor caso (cuando n es lo más grande posible), y ambos tienden a O(n³). Entiendo a lo que vas, si tu n vale 50, claramente será más eficiente el de n3 - log(n), pero la orden de complejidad va mas allá, no analiza valores discretos sino infinitos